# React.js Search check if the query exist in the Json data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to check if the client didn't get a result from his search but the problem is i trying to use useState but i fall in infinity loop every time he type a char
Code:

```js
const [searchExist, setSearchExist] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="commands__container">
      {Commands.filter((command) => {
        if (!isSearch) {
          return command.Categorie === `${CategorieName}`;
        } else {
          if (Commands.some((i) => i.Command.includes(isSearch))) {
            return command.Command.includes(isSearch);
          } else {
            setSearchExist(true);
            return command.Categorie === "xxx";
          }
        }
      }).map((item, index) => {
        if (searchExist) return <div key={index}>Not Found</div>;
        else return <div key={index}>{item.Command}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

What I'm trying to do is display a div when search query not exist but as you see infinity loop
Edit: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-mccarthy-rc488?file=/src/CommandsTable.js)

Comment: Could you provide more information by creating a demo? For example, https://codesandbox.io/s/minimal-react-k2uge . It is easier to understand the scenario.

Comment: cant you just check if `searchExists` has been set already? 
`if (Commands.some((i) => i.Command.includes(isSearch)) && !searchExist) {}`?

Comment: demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-mccarthy-rc488?file=/src/CommandsTable.js

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop happens because when you type a letter THAT IS NOT CONTAINED/INCLUDED inside the current commands, it goes to the ELSE statement here

```
 if (Commands.some((i) => i.Command.includes(isSearch))) {
        return command.Command.includes(isSearch);
      } else {
        setSearchExist(true);
        return command.Categorie === "xxx";
      }
```

Then it sets setSearchExist to True, the component does a re-render and it runs the logic again and because isSearch is still true and the letter is not included inside your command it falls inside the else statement again and sets your setSearchExists to True again and again and again, there is your infinite render.

Comment: so how can o solve this , how can i know if the search not exist

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do here.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is display a div when search query not exist but as you see infinity loop